# Update a Global Boolean to Start or Stop a Function

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt, blocking, gpio

I am writing an app in python that controls some LEDs based on GPIO state.  On the hardware, I listen for the GPIOs to change state and publish to an MQTT server running on a raspberry pi to control the LEDs.  One of the GPIOs should cause an LED to blink indefinitely until state changes again to turn it off, exactly how a car turn signal works.

So when the GPIO goes high I publish to a topic with the payload 'on'.  I then set a global variable

`blinker_status = True`

and then basically say (pseudo code)

`while (blinker_status) { blink }`

When I publish to that same topic with the payload 'off', I set the value of the global variable

`blinker_status = False`

I'm expecting the LED to stop blinking, but it doesn't.  I'm not sure if the issue is that MQTT is blocking?

Once I start the LED blinking, perhaps it's blocking the `on_message()` call back and it cannot process additional messages?  Should I isolate all of my subscriber clients into their own threads so that publishing to each topic is handled by its own `on_message()` call back?

I have code I can provide if necessary but at this point I'm stuck on trying to understand why my logic is flawed.

Below is my code

```
import time
from neopixel import *
from threading import Thread
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

mqtt_client = None

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT_LEFT = 150  # Number of LED pixels on the left strip.
LED_COUNT_RIGHT = 1  # Number of LED pixels on the right strip.
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA = 10  # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255  # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT = False  # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL_LEFT = 0  # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53
LED_CHANNEL_RIGHT = 1

# NOTE:  The WS2812B strip has red and green inverted, so red is actually (0, 255, 0) and green is (255, 0, 0)

left_blinker_status = False
right_blinker_status = False
blinker_status = False

# Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
# GPIO 18 is pin 12
left_strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT_LEFT, 18, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL_LEFT)
# GPIO 13 is pin 33
right_strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT_RIGHT, 13, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS,
                                LED_CHANNEL_RIGHT)
# Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
left_strip.begin()
right_strip.begin()


# MQTT functions
def start_mqtt():
    global mqtt_client
    try:
        system_id = 'Kawasaki Ninja'

        mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(client_id=system_id)
        mqtt_client.disable_logger()

        # Assign callback functions
        mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
        mqtt_client.on_message = on_message

        mqtt_client.connect(host='192.168.1.23')
        # Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
        # handles reconnecting.
        mqtt_client.loop_forever()

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in start_mqtt()! exception: {}'.format(ex))
        raise


# THe callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result code ' + str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() - if we lose connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe('ninja/#')  # The hash sign is wild-card


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global blinker_status
    global left_blinker_status
    global right_blinker_status

    print('{} {}'.format(msg.topic, str(msg.payload)))

    # Handle the brake topic
    if msg.topic == 'ninja/brake':
        if msg.payload == 'on':
            # BRAKE ON
            if not left_blinker_status:
                solidColor(left_strip, Color(0, 255, 0))
            if not right_blinker_status:
                solidColor(right_strip, Color(0, 255, 0))
        elif msg.payload == 'off':
            # BRAKE OFF
            if not left_blinker_status:
                solidColor(left_strip, Color(255, 255, 255))
            if not right_blinker_status:
                solidColor(right_strip, Color(255, 255, 255))

    # Handle the left turn signal topic
    elif msg.topic == 'ninja/left_turn_signal':
        # Left turn signal on
        if msg.payload == 'on':
            blinker_status = True
            left_blinker_status = True
            while left_blinker_status:
                blinker(blinker_status, left_strip)
        # Left turn signal off
        elif msg.payload == 'off':
            blinker_status = False
            left_blinker_status = False
            solidColor(left_strip, Color(255, 255, 255))

    # Handle the right turn signal topic
    elif msg.topic == 'ninja/right_turn_signal':
        # Right turn signal on
        if msg.payload == 'on':
            blinker_status = True
            right_blinker_status = True
            while right_blinker_status:
                blinker(blinker_status, right_strip)
        # Right turn signal off
        elif msg.payload == "off":
            blinker_status = False
            right_blinker_status = False
            solidColor(right_strip, Color(255, 255, 255))

    # Handle the party time topic
    elif msg.topic == 'ninja/party_time':
        # Party on
        if msg.payload == 'on':
            colorWipe(left_strip, Color(0, 255, 0))  # Red

        elif msg.payload == 'white':
            solidColor(left_strip, Color(255, 255, 255))

        elif msg.payload == 'wipe':
            colorWipe(left_strip, Color(0, 255, 0))  # Red

        elif msg.payload == 'off':
            solidColor(left_strip, Color(0, 0, 0))


# Neopixel functions
# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)


def solidColor(strip, color):
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
    strip.show()


def blinker(blinker_status, strip):
    while blinker_status:
        solidColor(strip, Color(65, 100, 0))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        solidColor(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))
        time.sleep(0.5)


try:
    while True:
        mqtt_thread = Thread(target=start_mqtt, args=())
        mqtt_thread.isDaemon()
        mqtt_thread.start()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up your post so that it's easier to read?  Having everything in one long paragraph with no code blocks makes it hard to read.

Comment: @DanielWalker I've updated the format, per your suggestion.  If you'd like for me to post the code, I can do that as well.  But I don't know that the code is necessarily where I'm stuck at this point, but rather my understanding of how MQTT works and the blocking/non-blocking nature of the ```on_message()``` callback handler.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess, at a bare minimum you should include your `on_message()` function.

Comment: You should run you blinking code in a thread and release your on_message ASAP. Are you able to publish anything else while you blinking is on?

Comment: @DamienLEFEVRE  I think that is the issue - if I call a ```while (True)``` loop is it going to block the ```on_message()``` handler and stop handling additional messages?  I can publish additional messages, honestly can't recall if those additional messages were showing up in the ```on_message()``` handler print statements.  It's been over a week since I was testing.  I want to say 'yes' otherwise I shouldn't be posting here lol (yet).

Comment: I don't know the internals of the MQTT library you are using but if on_message is called from an event loop, you never release it, so no new message can be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_message` callback is run on the MQTT client's network thread, if you block that thread you will not be able to send or receive any more messages.

You should NOT be doing any blocking or long running actions in this (or any of the client callbacks), you should be setting flags in a state machine and using those changes to control other threads.